# Better Autocorrection on Galaxy Note similar to Blackberry?

Tags: keyboard, samsung-galaxy-note, auto-correct

I got my first android device ever and it is the galaxy note.  Previously I was on a blackberry.

At the moment, I dislike the auto correction on the Galaxy Note.  If I want to type "and" but accidentally typed "abd", the autocorrect puts "abduction".  With my old blackberry, typing "abd" will display the suggested autocomplete inline.  If you press the space bar, then "abd" remains.  If you press enter key, then it will display the suggested autocomplete of "abduction".  This is great, because you can easily choose between abd or abduction without needing to look to a separate userinterface control for autocompelte suggestions and moving your fingers to a separate userinterface control.

Can anyone recommend a blackberry like keyboard for android?  Or just somethign that let's me easily choose "abd" instead of "abduction" when I mispell "and"?

Answer (score 2):

There's a keyboard better that that of Blackberry: [SwiftKey X](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.touchtype.swiftkey.phone.trial). Believe me, you'll love its Artificial Intelligence based suggestions. It learns from your typing habits to suggest you better. And, it can learn from Twitter, Facebook, Gmail and RSS Feed too (Quick Learning).

Answer (score 0):

You can try default Android keyboard. Search for Gingerbread keyboard or Icecream sandwich keyboard in play store.